# How do I bring my footer back up

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to bring my footer back up..there is too much space between the rest of the body. I don't understand what is keeping it so far down. The link to the page is. 
http://rwarner10.mydevryportfolio.com/WGD232/ProjectMilestone/aboutme.html

Here is my CSS3 code for that page.

```
/*---about me---*/
#japhyryder{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 350px;



}
#ryanimg{
   float: left;
   padding-left: 95px;
   margin-top: -185px;

}
#ryan{
   margin-left: 450px;
   margin-top: 50px;

 }

#bio{
   text-align: left;
   margin-right: 10em;
   margin-left: 450px;
   padding: 0px;   
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bring back up"?

Comment: If you go to the link you can see that there is way too much space between the content and the footer. If you view the other pages you can see how the pages are meant to look.

Comment: I'm sorry..let me upload the page quick..that isn't the correct one.

Comment: ok...it is up now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I also am not understanding why I have to use such big margins to the right when it is floated right. I am getting the feeling that something is blocking the elements

Comment: It is correct..I uploaded the correct file. I just checked.

Comment: I am working on it now.

Comment: Your webpage is a mess, you need to place the different sections inside divs.

Comment: I know it is..I'm trying to fix it, my teacher is not very good and isn't offering much help.

Answer (score 0):

You specify a `max-width` for `div#wrapper` (the source of the right margin?); specifying a `max-height` would limit the the space above the footer.

Comment: that is one way, but the rest of the pages have no problem with the footer..there is something in the way of the footer but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: @floyd: It is almost as big on the Contact page.

Comment: yes, I guess your right. I would like it to be closer though like on the home page.

Comment: I did manage to get it moved up a bit more. Thanks for helping.